# How many arrangements are there for the $8$ letters of the word VISITING?

Tags: combinatorics

How many arrangements are there for the $8$ letters of the word VISITING?

Solution:

So there are $\binom{8}{8}$, meaning 8 choose 8. But this gives a $8$ letter set not $8$ letter words, therefore

$\binom{8}{8}\times 8!$

**1) Is this logic correct?**
**2) How do I evaluate $\binom{8}{8}\times 8!$**

Comment: Try to answer your question first for two and three and four letter words with no repeated letters. Then suppose one letter occurs twice and see what happens. By the way, " 8 choose 8" is just 1. You should think rather than guessing formulas.

Comment: If all the letters would be different you would get $8!$ amount of words. Your number is even bigger than that so no it’s not correct. And this is for sure a duplicate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If all the letters were different, there would be $8!$ ways to arrange them.

But there are three $I$'s. You get a whole bunch of repeats in the $8!$ ways. How do you account for the three $I$'s? (How many times do you repeat each arrangement with a naïve counting?)

Spoiler:

> $8!/3!$

Comment: so then this would be the final answer?

Comment: The spoiler has the answer. I hope you understand the question better.

Comment: okay i believe i understand what you are saying, see if the following makes sense to you

There are $8!$ distinct ways to rearrange $8$ unique letters, but here we have $3$ that are indistinguishable (the III). So every arrangement is one from $3!$ that are indistinguishable. Thus the count we seek is: the ways to rearrange $8$ symbols when $3$ are indistinguishable. $$\dfrac{8!}{3!}$$

Comment: Yes, you've got it.

Comment: thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you have $8$ distinct objects then there are $8!$ factorial ways to arrange them. so for example there are $8!$ ways of arranging the symbols $VI_1SI_2TI_3NG$. However, in our case each $I_i$ simply has the value $I$, so for us $VI_1SI_2TI_3NG$ is exactly the same as $VI_2SI_1TI_3NG$, so we do not count them separately. Hence there are less than $8!$ distinct ways of arranging the letters of $VISITOR$. In fact for each arrangement of letters there are exactly $3!$ ways of permuting the $I_j's$ so that the arrangement is the same when we replace each $I_j$ with $I$. Hence we need to reduce the count of $8!$ by a factor of $3!$.

Comment: so $\frac{8!}{3!}$?

Comment: Yes, as John says.